# Remove quotation marks around a number (while leaving other quotes)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to replace all text like this:

```
"latitude": "32.336533",
```

with this:

```
"latitude": 32.336533,
```

I'm using Notepad++.

Answer (score 10):

Using Regex use the following pattern:

```
"([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)"
```

and Replace with:

```
\1
```

This worked for me with `replace all` function of notepad++.  It would find `"12."` too and remove the double quotes.  For a more comprehensive search use this Regex pattern:

```
"(\-{0,1}[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,1})"
```

which actually will find negative numbers as well and matches floats only with digits after the decimal point.

**Explanation:**

it will match

```
    "             ; a leading double quote
    (             ; followed by the outer subpattern (in backreference \1:
      \-{0,1}       ; an optional minus sign
      [0-9]+        ; followed by 1 or more decimal digits (could be replaced by \d)
      (             ; followed by the next subpattern
         \.           ; a decimal point
         [0-9]+       ; followed by 1 or more digits
      ){0,1}        ; maximal 1 occurrence of this subpattern, and it's optional
    )             ; end of the outer subpattern
    "             ; followed by the trailing double quote
```

Backreference `\1` includes everything in the outer subpattern including the inner one, if it exists. You could use `\d` for the `[0-9]` classes and use the question mark `?` instead of the last `{0,1}` group. Remember that the use of the `?` may change the greediness of patterns.

---

**Example:**

the text in notepad++ with following lines

```
"latitude": "-32.336533",
"latitude": "32.336533",
"foo": "14"
"bla": "12."
"to7": "12.a"
```

will be changed  after applying "Replace all" to

```
"latitude": -32.336533,
"latitude": 32.336533,
"foo": 14
"bla": "12."
"to7": "12.a"
```

Comment: This assumes that each number is a floating point number.  However, this is the more correct answer thus far.

Comment: @KronoS The original did match integers too. I've edited the regexp to include negative numbers and demanding at least one digit after the decimal point (last group optional).

Comment: Your updated answer works great and is a great solution to the problem handling cases where the user probably wants string types to stay string and actual numbers to be converted to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Regex match

```
"([\d\.]+)"
```

Replace with

```
\1
```

Comment: This doesn't handle negative numbers, and will match unwanted strings like `"..."`, `"3..2"`, `"2014.05.13"`, or `"127.0.0.1"`.